# Remove text from a string

Tags: php, string

`http://site.com/js/script.js?ver=1.0`

How can I remove the query arguments from a string like this?

(`?ver=1.0`)

Comment: Perhaps `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` is an easier way to get to your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this for different, longer, or possibly unknown query strings, take your pick from the following methods:

```
$substr = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '?'));

$regex = preg_replace('/\?(.*)/', '', $string);

$array = explode('?', $string);
$str = current($array);
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove everything after (and including) the first `?` character:

```
$str = 'http://site.com/js/script.js?ver=1.0';
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '?'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = str_replace('?ver=1.0', '', $string);
```

Or if this example only represents a laundry list of additional query values, you could explode on the question mark and your first resulting array key will be the desired string.

```
$array = explode('?', $string);
echo $array[0]; // http://site.com/js/script.js
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the question mark and everything after it:

```
$string = 'http://site.com/js/script.js?ver=1.0';

$string = array_shift( explode('?', $string) );
```